# How to get access to a TIWApplication from other computers

Tags: intraweb, c++builder-10.2-tokyo

I am using Intraweb version 14.0.0 on C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo. 
I have constructed a test application using TIWServerController and TIWApplication.

When I run the application it shows the controls on the web browser, but I am not being able to get access to the same application using another web browser window of the same kind.

How can I use IntraWeb to serve the same application to several users from different locations of the same local network ?

Thank you very much.

Jayme Jeffman

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. The version of IntraWeb (14.00) which was added to C++Builder 10.2 Tokyo community edition does not work the same way as it does on the paid version which has the 14.2.10 attached to the paid edition of C++Builder.

I have asked to a collegue of mine who has the paid edition to build the same test application I have made and everything is now working fine. Including the port number that now is always the same set in the IWServerController instead of start each time with a new one.